# Print HTTP protocol version of given url

Tags: http, axios, httprequest, protocols, httpresponse

I'm building a webapp using Vue CLI to analyze http responses. I'm using axios to make get requests and a chrome extension which allows to send cross-domain requests.

My goal is to print HTTP protocol version, as I can't find it in the axios response but I can see it using chrome dev tools.

Here how I handled the axios request:

```
axios({
    method: this.userMethod,
    url: url,
  })
    .then((r) => {
      this.response = r;
      };
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
```

Where 'url' is a URL object.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MfAr.png) is the kind of response I get from a site (StackOverflow in this example) once I activate the CORS extension.

What I want to get is the "h2" protocol version that chrome dev tools shows. My goal is to take that and print it on screen, but I can't find it in the axios response.
I've read about 'curl' using the command line, Is that possible with Javascript too or am I completely off path?

[A screenshot of the response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj3F9.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.